# Мне необходимо "прибить" футер к концу моего приложения в ангуляре

Tags: css, html5, angularjs

мне необходимо прибить футер который создан в отдельном компоненте к самому низу страницы [image: это моя основная страница сайта и там футер находится как положено внизу но если я добавлю товары в корзину и перейду в нее то получиться то что футер находится где то посередине[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5qlT.png)

Comment: position: fixed; bottom: 0

Comment: проблема которая была не изменилась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я уже выкладывал подобное